# Not able to play DRM content in Chrome headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, drm

I tried launching chrome headless with the below arguments.

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu https://www.netflix.com/
```

I then used the chrome debugging port to navigate within the app and play a DRM protected video. Video never plays. But this works if i play a clear content.

is there any flag that i need to turn on to make DRM work in chrome headless mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. What you are looking for is specifically the EME keySystems, that are not currently available in headless mode.

There is a [bug filed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=788662) with Google that requests this be changed, but that bug is still not resolved. I suggest you follow that for any updates.

Comment: Thanks for the info @colde.